# Aspx.net and C# masterpage.cs error

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I got a very strange problem at the moment, i'm creating a website with aspx.net and c#. On my masterpage i have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Pages/Overzicht.aspx")
        {
            pagOverzicht.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Pages/Defeault.aspx")
        {
            pagPackage.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Pages/page1.aspx")
        {
            pagToevoegen.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Pages/page2.aspx")
        {
            pagWijzigen.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
```

I am trying to achieve that the current page where u are on is active. When i create this in my test environment it works but when i publish it on my server it won't work.

i already tried to hit ctrl+f5 but nothing works.

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Is your test environment running from a virtual directory? When you go to the default page, is http://www.example.com/Pages/Default.aspx, or is it something like http://www.example.com/Something/Pages/Default.aspx ?

Comment: just add `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` to log and see it value on test environment and on server

Comment: Do you mean asp.net? aspx.net is not a thing.

Comment: I indeed meant asp.net. I will try what grundy says. And it is example.com/something/pages/defeault.aspx

Comment: Change the equal operation with `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/Pages/Overzicht.aspx")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the equal operation with       HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/Pages/Overzicht.aspx")‌​. –  th1rdey3 15 hours ago

this was the thing that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the css class file is uploaded, and make sure to clear cache. You can see if the file is already there by firbug or chrome dev tools